Understanding the definition of congruences over a lattice
Let $(L, \land, \lor)$ a lattice and $\theta$ a binary relation over $L$. We say $\theta$ is a congruence iff
$$
x_0\theta x_1, y_0 \theta y_1 \Rightarrow (x_0 \lor y_0)\theta(x_1 \lor y_1)
$$
(and the same for $\land$).
I am confused by the required cardinality of $\theta$. Any equivalence relation is isomorphic to a partition over its set. The definition does not require (explicitly) that $x_0, x_1$ and $y_0, y_1)$ be distinct. So does that mean we could have a congruence where an element is only equivalent to itself?
To take a simple example, let $(\{1,2,3,4\}, \max, \min)$ be a lattice. Let $\theta$ be the binary relation induced by the partition $\{\{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{4\}\}$. How could we apply the definition of congruence to test if $\theta$ is one? Can we say that it is a congruence because
$$
1\theta 1, 2\theta 2, \text{ and } (1\max 2)\theta(1 \max 2)
$$
and so to for all other elements?

Yes, a congruence can have singleton classes.

Equality is a congruence with only singleton classes. This has nothing to do with lattices.

Sorry, there was a typo, the statement was: "any equivalence relation is isomorphic to a partition over a set". What I mean by this is that there is a perfect correspondance (i.e. a bijection) between the set of possible equivalence relations and the set of possible partitions of a set; any equivalence relation can be represented through a partition and vice-versa. If this is not the correct use of the term "isomorphic", I apologize - I'm not a mathematician.

Thanks @NoahSchweber for answering my question.
